# Get name of control when mouse hovers over it C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am adding ComboBoxes dynamically at runtime as shown below.
The problem that I am having is that i do not know which of the comboboxes the user is using.

For eg. The user decides to add 5 comboBoxes to the form, and then goes to the first comboBox,and selects a value, I need to retrieve the value of that comboBox.

**What the below code is doing - My approach**

I am adding a comboBox to a FlowlayoutPanel and the retrieve its name based on the mouse co-ordinates.... this by the way is not working... and I have no idea what to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int count = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count += 1;

        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.Name = count.ToString();
        cb.MouseHover += new EventHandler(doStuff);

        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = count.ToString();

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cb);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lb);
    }

    public void doStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = flowLayoutPanel1.GetChildAtPoint(Cursor.Position).Name;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
cb.SelectionChangeCommitted += selectionChangedHandler

...

void selectionChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
  label1.Text = cb.Name;
  // Do whatever else is needed with the combo box
}
```

The [SelectionChangeCommitted event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is "*raised only when the user changes the combo box selection*", which sounds like what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

The combobox that raised the event in your doStuff-eventhandler is in the sender-parameter. Try casting it to a checkbox likte this:

`ComboBox boxThatRaisedTheEvent = (ComboBox)sender;`

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = ((ComboBox)this.GetChildAtPoint(pt)).Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void DoStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    var name = (comboBox != null ? comboBox.Name : null);
}
```

this code casts the 'sender' parameter to a ComboBox object and if the cast is done correctly assings the ComboBox name to the string 'name', otherwise 'name' is null.

Tip: The C# coding style suggests that method names should start with capitalized letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().FirstOrDefault(cb => cb.Name.Equals(NAME_OF_COMBOBOX))
```

Or better:

```
ComboBox box = (ComboBox)sender;
```